# How to stay connected with MySQLi from php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm setting up a new website and i want to enter some registrations in my MySQLi database.

I want to stay connected with the DB and not to making a new connection every time in a sub-page.

In the Home page i'm starting the connection like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Website");     
    if (!$con)    {                                                   
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL.";
    exit;         }
    if($con){       echo "Successful connect";}
```

The Home page have some href that navigate to other php pages.
For example:

```
 <a href="/InsertInDatabase.php">Insert</a>
 <a href="/SearchDatabase.php">Search</a>
 <a href="/DeletefromDatabase.php">Delete</a>
```

Into every php now i'm making again a connection with the DB

**InsertInDatabase.php**

```
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Website");     
    if (!$con)    {                                                   
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL.";
    exit;         }
    if($con){       echo "Successful connect";}
```

**SearchDatabase.php**

```
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Website");     
    if (!$con)    {                                                   
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL.";
    exit;         }
    if($con){       echo "Successful connect";}
```

and I do this for every new php..... 
Is there a way to stay connected from HomePage.php and not to do this every time again and again?

Comment: Why is it a problem connecting to the database, probably better than holding a connection open.

Answer (score 2):

you can add the connection codes into a php and include them in every pages that you want to connect. This way, you do not have to type that long wall of codes.

e.g

**db.php**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Website");     
if (!$con)    {                                                   
echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL.";
exit;         }
if($con){       echo "Successful connect";}
```

**InsertInDatabase.php**

```
<?php include 'db.php';?>
```

**SearchDatabase.php**

```
<?php include 'db.php';?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it now

Comment: No problem. Hope it helps!

Comment: It is always a good design decision to create at least on library php file for common constants, classes and functions.